# How to extract relevant text from github

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, python-requests

I have a simple html file on github with value of 0.5 in it.  I am wanting this script to read 0.5 and as this is 0.5, it should not update but it keeps trying to update.  I have used txt files but same issue.

```
import urllib.request
import requests

currentVersion = "0.5" #########################Current
URL = urllib.request.urlopen('https://github.com/Hardcorekila/updater/blob/main/0.5.html')

data = URL.read() ################If Url Read = current version, it is up to date
print(data)
if (data == currentVersion):
    print("App is up to date!")
else:
    print("App not up to date, downloading new version now!")
    newVersion = requests.get("https://github.com/Hardcorekila/updater/raw/main/main.exe")
    open("main.exe", "wb").write(newVersion.content)
```

printed data:

```
b'\n\n\n\n\n\n\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en" data-color-mode="auto" data-light-theme="light" data-dark-theme="dark" data-a11y-animated-images="system">\n  <head>\n    <meta charset="utf-8">\n  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://github.githubassets.com">\n  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com">\n  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com">\n  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/">\n  <link
```

File on github[image]

Comment: I know that this is not your question, but are you aware that there is the option to see the content of files on GitHub in raw format? Just click on the "raw" button. Like this you get redirected to a page which only displays the content. It should be easier to automatically read this URL instead of the whole web page

Comment: Or you could use the [GitHub API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents#get-repository-content) to get the file contents; you have to extract the `content` field from the JSON response, and then base64-decode it.